# Raindrop rolling downhill on a surface z=f(x,y)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

A raindrop falls on a point $f(x_o,y_o)$ of the surface $z=f(x,y)$.

How do I find the direction in which the raindrop will roll downhill, given that the trajectory of the raindrop until it hits on the surface is parallel to the $y-axis$ (the $y-axis$ being the "vertical" one)?

Will it roll in the direction of the steepest descent?

Comment: Yes, the assumption made in these problems is that the velocity vector is in the steepest direction downhill. (It has always seemed to me that the tangential component of *acceleration* is in that direction, but that's way too hard!)

Comment: @TedShifrin The friction between a droplet and a surface is usually so high in practice that it doesn't matter (unless you have some kind of repellant coating or something).

Comment: @Arthur, interesting point.

Comment: Hint: Gradient.

Comment: You say that the $y$-axis is the "vertical" one, but $z=f(x,y)$ is described as "a surface".  I suspect that $z$ was meant to denote the vertical axis and $x,y$ are orthogonal horizontal directions.